# Pandas column is the sum if three criteria are met (similar to sumproduct)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am trying to create a new column which values are the sum of another column but only if two column contain a specific value.

**origin_data_frame (df_o)**

```
month   state       count
2015-12 Alabama     31359
2015-12 Alaska      245
2015-12 Arizona     2940
2015-12 Arkansas    4076
2015-12 California  119166
2015-12 Colorado    3265
2015-12 Connecticut 12190
2015-12 Delaware    297
2015-12 DC          16
....... ...         ..
```

**target_data_frame (df_t)** ('counts' is not there):

```
   level_0          level_1        Veterans, 2011-2015  counts
0  h_pct_vet        California     1777410              <?>
1  h_pct_vet        Texas          1539655              <?>  
2  h_pct_vet        Florida        1507738              <?>
3  h_pct_vet        Pennsylvania   870770               <?> 
4  h_pct_vet        New York       828586               <?>
5  l_pct_vet        Vermont        44708                <?>
6  l_pct_vet        Wyoming        48505                <?>
```

**the problem:**

*counts* should include a value that is the sum of count if month is between '2011-01' and '2015-12' and state equals "level_1".

I can get a sum for all count in the time frame:

```
counts_2011_2015 = df_o['count'][(df_o['month'] >= '2011-01-01') & (df_o['month'] <= '2015-12-31')].sum()
```

What I tried so far but without success:

```
df_t['counts'] = df_o['count'][(df_o['month'] >= '2011-01-01') & (df_o['month'] <= '2015-12-31') & (df_o['state'] == df_t['level_1'])].sum()
```

It raises a ValueError: "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects".

What I found so far (dropping indexes) is not helpful so I would be thankful if someone has an idea

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping them by state first and then merging them with df_t:

```
# untested code
counts = (
    df_o[df_o.month.between("2011-01", "2015-12")]
    .groupby("state")["count"].sum()
    .reset_index(name="counts")
)

df_t.merge(counts, left_on="level_1", right_index=True, how="left")
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [@pomber's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49564882/9209546), if you wish to avoid an explicit merge, is to align indices, assign a series from your `groupby`, then reset index.

```
df_t = df_t.set_index('level_1')

df_t['counts'] = df_o.loc[df_o.month.between('2011-01', '2015-12')]\
                     .groupby('state')['count'].sum()

df_t = df_t.reset_index()
```